# Is it possible to surround an input field or select with a color dynamically?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

Can I surround an input or multiples inputs with a specific color, based on some conditions?

So the idea would be that within TypeScript I can change, add or remove the surrounding color of an input like image below:

[image]

Right now I am doing this:

```html
<tr>  [ngStyle]="{ 'background-color': getColorByRegistrationInsertStatus(registration) }"</tr>
```

And then somewhere in my TypeScript I am calling this function:

```js
getColorByRegistrationInsertStatus(registrationControl: AbstractControl): string {
    switch (registrationControl.get('registrationInsertStatus')?.value) {
      case RegistrationInsertStatus.Success: return '#52c41a';
      case RegistrationInsertStatus.Error: return '#ff6163';
      default: return 'white';
    }
  }
```

That code does this:

- get the `registrationInsertStatus`
- if is Success then return green
- if it is Error return false

Now that is very ugly in terms of style so can I change the radius or add a color to sort of like "fit" content and have the same like below image:

[image]

### UPDATE

I added this to my css:

```css
.ng-select {
    &.success {
        outline: none !important;
        border:1px solid red;
        box-shadow: 0 0 10px #719ECE;
    }
}
```

Ho can i use it on my html? Is it like this?

```html
<ng-select [ng-select.success]="someFunction(someVariable)"></ng-select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can. Using `[ngStyle]` is an option. I'd recommend using CSS classes instead with something like `[class.success]="someFunction(someVariable)"` (boolean) if you want to define style more specifically.

Then if you are using SCSS for example you just have to add something like `&.success { ... }` to your stylesheet at the right place depending on the scope you want to use for this class.

example:

HTML

```
<div class="my-class" [class.success]="someFunction(someVariable)"></div>
```

SCSS

```
.my-class {

  ...default style...

  &.success {
    ...styles to apply on success...
  }

}
```

Comment: Okay so how would i declare my scss in html?

Comment: And in my html?

Comment: It works like this `[class.xxx]="boolean"` with xxx being the conditional class name you want to apply and boolean a function or whatever. The resulting HTML when the condition is true will look like this `<div class="my-class success"></div>`

Comment: Thanks for the answer although i am getting can't bind to ng select since it isn't a known property of ng-select. My html is this: `<ng-select [ng-select.success]="true"></ng-select>`

Comment: use `[class.sucess]` instead as suggested, it is just a subclass, and in your css `.ng-select` is not a class

Answer (score 0):

Forms in angular have a `ng-valid` / `ng-invalid` class when you use them with the (reactive) forms module.

So depending on what you wish to achieve :

```css
input.ng-invalid {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

input.ng-valid {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```